# Can I prevent virtualbox from being closed once launched in fullscreen mode?

Tags: virtualbox

I have built a custom VirtualBox guest image based on Ubuntu for others to use during a roadshow. It will run on a wide variety of host OSs. **How can I prevent passersby from inadvertently closing the guest image while it is running**?

Ultimately, I would like the guest image to run in a sort of kiosk mode that requires some know-how to exit.

Comment: So... you want to lock someone in a VM? Any particular reason? And you should specify your host (and maybe guest) OS.

Comment: @Bob We are distributing a bundle for a client to show around on roadshows, and don't have much control over what their host system runs. The guest OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you considered [distrubuting your bundle as a live-cd](http://www.howtogeek.com/109736/how-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-or-usb/) based on Ubuntu instead? This may serve you better.

Comment: VirtualBox by itself can't do this AFAIK, and if you don't control the host there's even less chance that you'll be able to do it.

Comment: @JeremyW Good idea, I'll think about that option the next time we run into the same situation.